# intercepting Omniauth callback with javascript in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am trying to implement Omniauth and Devise with multiple providers in Rails 3.2 app.

One tricky scenario is: user signs in via LinkedIn for the first time. Since linkedin does not provide user email, I won't know which account I should link this linkedin credentials to. So I want to intercept the callback to prompt a popup window that allows user to enter his email or username, before passing the credentials together with email to controller.

How should I go about this?